# a xe(la)texify script for WinEdt 6

Tags: xetex, winedt

I like how WinEdt has a PDFTeXify script, with an associated button, which re-runs everything necessary until you get a PDF, and also opens the PDF in a viewer. I want the same thing for XeTeX, but I'm finding it a bit difficult to make heads or tails of the PDFTexify script source. Has someone written such a script I might use?

Also, supposing I have it, can it be easily added to the menus, i.e. with something like

```
ITEM="-"
ITEM="PDFTeXify"
  CAPTION="XeTLaT&eXify"
  IMAGE="TeXXeLaTeX"
  SAVE_INPUT=1
  MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\XeLaTeXify.edt');"
  SHORTCUT="24656::Shift+Ctrl+e"
  REQ_FILTER=:something...
```

?

Comment: Did you try making a copy of the PDFTeXify details in the Execution Modes window, and adding the `--engine=xetex` switch? This works for me if I just alter the PDFTeXify settings, with needing to go near the menus.

Comment: I just did that, but I can't seem to get the file onto the menu, or the toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update to Version 7.

As you can read in [the WinEdt Discussion List](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/6904) this function is now included in WinEdt 7.